# How is this different from $(document).ready()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a difference between $().ready() and $(document).ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384204/is-there-a-difference-between-ready-and-document-ready)

I am trying to setup jquery ui tabs for a page and I used

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tabs').tabs();
});
```

which did not work. So I checked their example and saw a different syntax which now worked

```
$(function(){
    $('#tabs').tabs();
});
```

What's the difference between the two syntaxes?

Comment: Are you sure the first one didn't work?

Comment: You're missing a closing paren `)` in both.

Comment: It's the same thing. Read the jQuery docs: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: It's not the same thing. At least with jQuery UI. I tried the two repeatedly to be sure

Comment: @codingbiz I've used the `$(document).ready()` format many times, including _exactly_ as you have it above with an id `#tabs` to instantiate UI tabs.

Comment: Both should work perfectly fine as shown in the docs. If it's not working, you should check the JavaScript console to make sure there are no errors elsewhere and that jQuery is properly loading.

Comment: @Jon @Michael it was edited after I commented. I still have it open in the original tab where it's missing the trailing `);` in both snippets. If you edit within a certain amount of time, a few minutes maybe, it doesn't record a new revision.

Comment: Could you provide please jsfiddle example?

Comment: I'm sorry all I double checked it's working. thanks

Comment: Please help vote to close. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

They are equivelent. http://api.jquery.com/ready/

> The .ready() method is typically used with an anonymous function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called. 
});
```

> Which is equivalent to calling:

```
$(function() {  
  // Handler for .ready() called. 
});
```

> If .ready() is
>   called after the DOM has been initialized, the new handler passed in
>   will be executed immediately.